# Redirect output to subfolders that don't yet exist

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I currently redirect crontab script output to file in some folder that exists, like this:

```
echo "test" > `date "+/tmp/%Y%m%d_%H%M.log"`
```

I want to redirect output to subfolders, that maybe don't exists yet (`.../year/month/...`, so subfolders should be created:

```
echo "test" > `date "+/tmp/%Y/%m/%d_%H%M.log"`
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create the directory. The `-p` flag to mkdir achieves two things:

- Create the entire path
- Don't complain if the diretorry already exists

So:

```
mkdir -p  $(date "+/tmp/%Y/%m/") && echo "test" > $(date "+/tmp/%Y/%m/%d_%H%M.log")
```

Next time ask questions like this on unix.stackexchange please, it's a bit offtopic here.

Comment: I like one-liner with `&&` + `$(...)` is nicer than `\`...\``. Subquestion, If you know: canIi use multilines in crontab, like `5 * * * * command && \ (newline) command2 && \ (newline) command3`? p.s. I will use unix.SO nexttime.

Comment: If you want that, just wrap your commands in a small script and call the script from cron.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the folder(s) using `mkdir -p` command like:

```
mkdir -p `date "+/tmp/%Y/%m/"`
```

Then, you can execute your echo command safely.

```
echo "test" > `date "+/tmp/%Y/%m/%d_%H%M.log"`
```